# How to convert a uint16 stored as a little endian byte array to an int?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, integer, unsigned-integer

I'm receiving some data that is a little endian byte array that represents a uint16 but I want to store this in an `int`. I have wrapped this data into a `ByteBuffer` so I can call `ByteBuffer.get()` to get the next byte(s), but I am not sure how to convert these 2 bytes from uint16 to `int`.

```
    byte[] data = //From UDP socket
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    bb = bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    while(bb.hasRemaining()){
        int n = //What goes here?
    }
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main complexity is in my opinion how to represent a *uint16* in Java. I'd suggest to use Java *int* or Java *long*, because the least 16 bits have the same meaning as in *uint16* (but not Java *short*: it has 16 bits, but is signed).

1) If you receive *uint16* only, no chars, no other types, then the easiest would be following. Read 16 bits into a Java *short*, then convert it to *int*:

```
byte[] data = //From UDP socket
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
bb = bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

while(bb.hasRemaining()){
    short s = bb.getShort();
    int n = 0xFFFF & s;
    ...
}
```

2) If you receive not only *uint16*, but some other types like chars, then you can construct the value from 2 bytes:

```
byte[] data = //From UDP socket
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

while(bb.hasRemaining()) {
    if (consider next bytes as uint16) {
        byte b1 = bb.get();
        byte b2 = bb.get();
        int i1 = 0xFF & b1; // Consider b1 as int, not the same as "(int) b1"
        int i2 = 0xFF & b2; // Consider b2 as int, not the same as "(int) b2"
        int n = b2 * 256 + b1;
        ...
    } else {
        // Read next bytes as char or something other
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ByteBuffer.wrap()` method converts the array into a `HeapByteBuffer` class with an offset of 0 and a length equivalent to the array length being wrapped.  You can access two bytes using the method `bb.getShort(i)` but this will return negative numbers where you want unsigned ones.

Note that the "endiness" of the buffer is only relevant if you call methods such as `getShort()`.  If you access the bytes in the order you require, the buffer setting is not important.

Follow a similar approach to the `getShort()` method to get the data.  Here is the elements from the Bits class:

```
static short getShort(ByteBuffer bb, int bi, boolean bigEndian) {
    return bigEndian ? getShortB(bb, bi) : getShortL(bb, bi);
}

static short getShortL(ByteBuffer bb, int bi) {
    return makeShort(bb._get(bi + 1),
                     bb._get(bi    ));
}

static short getShortB(ByteBuffer bb, int bi) {
    return makeShort(bb._get(bi    ),
                     bb._get(bi + 1));
}

static private short makeShort(byte b1, byte b0) {
    return (short)((b1 << 8) | (b0 & 0xff));
}
```

So your example could could be something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Long rawData = 0x01F2030405F60708L;
    byte[] x = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buf.putLong(rawData);
    buf.position(0);
    buf.get(x);
    for (byte xi : x)
        System.out.printf("%02X, ", xi); 
    System.out.println(""); 

    byte[] data = x;//From UDP socket
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    for (int i=0; i<data.length-1; i += 2) 
    {
        int n = ((bb.get(i+1) & 0xff) << 8) | (bb.get(i));
        System.out.printf("Hex: %04X int value: %d%n", n, n);
    }
}
```

Or, using getShort and setting the order of the buffer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Long rawData = 0x01F2030405F60708L;
    byte[] x = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buf.putLong(rawData);
    buf.position(0);
    buf.get(x);
    for (byte xi : x)
        System.out.printf("%02X, ", xi); 
    System.out.println(""); 

    byte[] data = x;//From UDP socket
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // Required to use getShort()
    bb.position(0);
    while(bb.hasRemaining()) 
    {
        int n = bb.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
        System.out.printf("Hex: %04X int value: %d%n", n, n);
    }
}
```

Both solutions provide the following output:

```
01, F2, 03, 04, 05, F6, 07, 08, 
Hex: F201 int value: 61953
Hex: 0403 int value: 1027
Hex: F605 int value: 62981
Hex: 0807 int value: 2055
```